# Complete 1st api call , edit its response and then make another call using the response

Tags: angular, observable

I am using callbacks for combining two observables :

```
this._containerService.portlist(this.locationDetails.LocationType)
        .subscribe(res=>{
          this.portId = res.filter(port=>port.portCode ==result.locationAddress.portCode)[0].id;
          this._portAddressService.getPortAddress(this.portId,this.locationDetails.LocationType).subscribe(res=>
            {
              this.portDetails = res.records[0];

}}
```

It is not an efficient method. Is there any way I can make use of an operator to complete the first observable , modify its response and then call another API using the response of the first API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ['switchMap'](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) operator.

```
this._containerService.portlist(this.locationDetails.LocationType)
    .pipe(
       switchMap(res => {
         this.portId = res.filter(port=>port.portCode ==result.locationAddress.portCode)[0].id;
         return this._portAddressService.getPortAddress(this.portId,this.locationDetails.LocationType
       }))
        .subscribe(res => this.portDetails = res.records[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding on Riorudo's answer, you can go further

```js
this._containerService
  .portlist(this.locationDetails.LocationType)
  .pipe(
    map(res => res.find(({ portCode }) => portCode === result.locationAddress.portCode),
    pluck('id'),
    switchMap(id => this._portAddressService.getPortAddress(id, this.locationDetails.LocationType),
    map(({ records }) => records[0]),
    tap(record => this.portDetails = record)
  ).subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Port details set');
  });
```

Very declarative, eases the reading so much